# Computing in the Image Bit Plane Slicing

Tags: java, image, bit-manipulation

Looking for some methods of image bit plane slicing, I found the following function. Event though I'm familiar with bitwise operations I don't understand this exact line of code :

```
 if (((fcol >>> d) & 1) > 0) col = 0xffffff;
```

Method for image bit plane slicing :

```
    private void transfrombit(int d) {

        transform = new BufferedImage(originalImage.getWidth(), originalImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
 
        for (int i = 0; i < originalImage.getWidth(); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < originalImage.getHeight(); j++) {

                int col = 0;
                int fcol = originalImage.getRGB(i, j);
                if (((fcol >>> d) & 1) > 0) col = 0xffffff;
                transform.setRGB(i, j, col);
            }
    }
```

Can somebody please explain me how the computation in the method above works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`((fcol >>> d) & 1) > 0` is a way to test whether bit `d` is set in `fcol`, an alternative to `(fcol & (1 << d)) != 0`, except it does not work when `d == 31` (but this in this context `d in [0 .. 23]` so that does not matter). `((fcol >>> d) & 1) != 0` would make it work for `d = 31` as well.

By the way the other form (`(fcol & (1 << d)) != 0`) has a potential advantage in this case, because `1 << d` is loop-invariant (and could be lifted out of the loop by the JIT compiler) so the test can potentially compile to fewer instructions than the first form, in which a shift per pixel is inevitable.

In this context, this logic is used to test bit `d` of every pixel, and create a bitmap with `0xffffff` for pixels that have that bit set and 0 otherwise.

Comment: does it mean that when we shift the value and its last bit is set to 1 then the color of the pixel will be 0xffffff (white) else the color is black?

Comment: @vajda yes that's what it means